# maven not executing my cucumber testRunner class or assocaited feature files

Tags: java, maven, testng, cucumber-java, testng.xml

I am trying to execute a testNg.xml test suite that in turn executes a cucumber test runner class via maven and not tests are triggered.
If I execute the testNG.xml directly from intelliJ, it works.
If I execute the feature file or testRunner, it works.

my testNG.xml file - sanityTestSuite.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="My UI Sanity Test Features">

    <test verbose="2" preserve-order="true" name="Sanity tests">

        <classes>
            <class name="com.runner.SanityTestRunner">
                <!-- <methods><include name="test1"/></methods> -->
            </class>
            
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

my TestRunner file - SanityTestRunner

```
package com.runner;
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;

@CucumberOptions
        (
                features = {"src\\test\\java\\com\\features"},
                //features = {"src\\test\\java\\com\\features\\LoginTest.feature"},

                glue = {"com.stepDef"},

                dryRun = false, strict = true, monochrome = true,

                //Report generator.
                plugin = {  "pretty", "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"},

                //Below statement can be used to tag the features that needs to be executed.
                tags = "@Sanity"

                //Below statement can be used to tag the features that NOT be executed.
                //tags = {"~@SanityTest"}
        )
public class SanityTestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests { }
```

my feature file - LoginTest.feature

```
@UITests
Feature: Verify basic user functionalities of the amazon portal

  Background:
    Given user opens the url in the browser


  @Sanity
    @userSignInToAmazonPortal
  Scenario Outline: Launch Amazon portal and sign in as admin user.
    Then user validates the loaded home page title as <homePageTitle>
    And user selects Sign In button
    And user validates the loaded sign in page title as <signInPageTitle>
    And user enters the credentials for <userType> user
    Then user Sign in must be successful

    Examples:
      | userType   |homePageTitle        |signInPageTitle |
      | admin      |Online Shopping site |Amazon Sign In  |
```

Commands I have used -
`mvn test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/java/com/features/LoginTest.feature" -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@Smoke" -Denvironment=qa`

`mvn test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/java/com/suite/sanityTestSuite.xml" -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@Sanity" -Denvironment=qa`

`mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @userSignInToAmazonPortal"`

Answer (score 0):

Below code was disabled in my pom.xml file-

```
                   <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
```

The above dependency enabled me to execute the testNG.xml file via command-`mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=src/test/java/com/suite/sanityTestSuite.xml -Denvironment=uat`,
however this command doesn't work-
`mvn test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/java/com/suite/sanityTestSuite.xml"`
-Dcucumber.filter.tags="@Sanity" -Denvironment=qa